# How to handle router outlet for angular project with two main part

Tags: angular, module, routes

I have a project with two main part, one for anonymous user and other for user control panel.

I created separate module for each part. and I have some module in each main module. How can I handle routing for components

Answer (score 2):

You can use two major routes with lazy loading

```
Routes = [
    {
        path: 'anonymous-user',
        loadChildren: 'module1',
    },
    {
        path: 'control-panel',
        loadChildren: 'module2',
    },
]
```

The two modules can have corresponding routing configurations inside their routing modules.

Example: (module1-routing.module.ts)

```
Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: AbcComponent,
        children: [
            // child routes
        ],
    },
    {
        // other routes
    }
];
```

You can read https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules for lazy loading

Comment: Yeah, that's true. but each component have different style, it means, I have different base and navigation for each component. then I need handle router outlet. how can i do that??

Comment: I'm not very clear about your comment. can you explain a little more of post a diagram regarding your application/ routing structure?